# How to override default S3 function in R?

Tags: r, r-s3

I want to override the default predict.lm function due to a bug:

```
library(datasets)
# Just a regular linear regression
fit <- lm(mpg~disp+hp+wt+drat, data=mtcars)
termplot(fit, terms=2, se=T)
```

Gives this error:

```
Error in predict.lm(model, type = "terms", se.fit = se, terms = terms) : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

I know where the bug is and I've sent an email that awaits approval by the core mailing list but in the meantime I would like to test my own predict.lm function to fix this. I've understood that I need to redefine the S3 function for predict but when running this code:

```
setMethod("predict", "lm", predict.lm2)
getMethod("predict", "lm")
```

The getMethod returns my new function as expected but the termplot still runs the old function. The `methods("predict")` shows also that the old predict.lm is still there and I think it might be the call-order or something that I need to adjust. Anyone familiar with how to do this?

Comment: You could try setting the class of your model. `class(fit) <- c("lm2","lm")`

Comment: It complains then about lacking a definition for the lm2 class

Comment: You're not working with S3 but with S4 when you use setMethod. That can give trouble.

Comment: @JorisMeys: hmm... it works now but should I be using setOldClass() instead of setClass() - what advantage does that give me?

Comment: I'm just saying that because predict uses S3 inheritance (it is not an S4 generic), which means that any S3 inheritance has priority over S4 inheritance. Meaning that if you have an S4 method predict for lm and an S3 method predict.lm, R will always use the latter one. See the section _Methods for S3 Generic Functions_ in `?Methods`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@James's comment suggests to define your own `lm2` class,
that extends `lm`, and to implement `predict.lm2`.

```
class(fit) <- c("lm2", class(fit))
predict.lm2 <- function(...) { 
  # The function with your bugfix
  cat("Inside predict.lm2\n")
  predict.lm(...) 
}
termplot(fit, terms=2, se=T)
```

Comment: Thanks, this almost solves the problem although my bug-fixed predict.lm2 function causes a minor error: could not find function "qr.lm" - I guess this is due to some internal function of the lm class. How do I get access to the internal functions of lm? I've pasted my predict.lm2 function [here on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/FARH1gC0)

Comment: Since the function is not exported, you have to explicitly specify the namespace: `stats:::qr.lm`, every time it appears.